# The confusion about the way how IIFE works

Tags: javascript, iife

I am beginner at JavaScript and faced the confusion concerning the way IIFE works in JavaScript. That is, I got that it is used basically to escape variable is assigned to a global variable to avoid collisions. But here is the thing, say, we have a code like:

```js
var number = 7;

(function() {
  var number = 7;
  alert(number);
})();
//In this code collision does not happen due to IIFE
```

But what if I write:

```js
var number = 7;

function num() {
  var number = 7;
  alert(number);
}

/*In this code there does not happen collisions and 
number variable is not assigned to the global scope as well. So, why use IIFE?*/
num();
```

Comment: why do you think the local variable is assigned to the global one?

Comment: Both versions are the same, just in the second one you name the function and execute it separately, in the first one this is just done together.

Comment: @IngoBürk, thank you for your comments, Yeah I know, but as I understood IIFE is basically used to escape collisions of variable in global variable. And since in both codes there is no collision then I can use the second code instead of IIFE. Or I understood the concept of IIFE incorrectly.

Comment: There is an extra global `num` function in the second. That's about it.

Comment: An IIFE is just a function that is *immediately invoked* and is not named in the global scope. The scoping doesn't change based on whether it's immediate or not. Basically, it allows you to run code without specifically calling a method in the global scope while also having the scoping benefits you called out.

Comment: Because the function can be anonymous, and u cannot access the variable from outside the scope.

Comment: @NinaScholz, Nina thank you for your comments, what I cannot understand is that why use IIFE to avoid assignment of variable to global scope when I can use the second code which also ensures that var number which is inside function is not attached to global scope

Comment: Any link that made you think IIFE is used to avoid assignment of variable to global scope, will help to answer. I think it's used not to be re-assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) has more than one use. The one that you're focusing on is that an IIFE doesn't pollute the global scope when declaring a variable within it (or any other functions/methods).

Another important thing using an IIFE does is that it allows your code to immediately run **without someone else's code interfering**. Also, an IIFE runs without having to call a function **by name** that would presumably exist in the *global* scope.

The key here is that your code is both: not interfering with things in the global scope, and is protected from outside influence since anything in the global scope could mistakenly be overwritten.

> ...you are shielding your code from someone who may change your globals accidentally, or sometimes intentionally!

Checkout this medium article on [Mastering IIFEs](https://medium.com/@vvkchandra/essential-javascript-mastering-immediately-invoked-function-expressions-67791338ddc6) for more info.

---

Update

A good example of why your second example *could* negatively effect something is this:

If you import a library of some kind, and it has a method named `num` (that the library used internally) in the global scope (because it didn't use an IIFE), your second example would overwrite that method, and make it unusable within the library.

The key here is that it's not just scoping. The variables declared within any method are scoped to that method, not the global scope. **But a named function is within the global scope.**

Comment: does the variable inside function in the second code also not pollute global scope?

Comment: Again, as stated in the first sentence, and IIFE is not just about scope. The variable declared in the function will not affect global scope, however the named function will.

Answer (score 2):

You are making a big confusion. IIFE doesn't affect how the local and global variables work.

There is no difference between your two examples regarding the global and local variables.

Both declare the global variable `number` and initialize it with `7` (outside the function) and a variable that is also named `number` and initialized also with `7` inside the function. The variable inside the function "covers" the global one; the global variable `number` cannot be used inside the function (by simply using the `number` name) and the `alert()` call uses the local variable.

You can check this easily using these variants of your code:

```js
var number = 7;

(function() {
  var number = 6;
  alert('local variable: ' + number);
})();
alert('global variable: ' + number);
```

and

```js
var number = 7;

function num() {
  var number = 6;
  alert('local variable: ' + number);
}
num();
alert('global variable: ' + number);
```

The two code snippets above have almost identical effects. They declare a function then execute it.

The only difference is that the second one creates a function named `num` in the global name space.

Some times we don't want to create a named function. For example, when it is used only once. In such a case, when a function is declared then called only once, an IIFE is used. It packs the declaration and the call into a single expression and it doesn't leave behind a function that is not to be used again.